# Can't show error in userFieldArray in react form hook

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form

```
const EventProposalSession = ({
  register,
  errors,
  index,
  control,
  watch,
  handleRemoveEvent,
  open,
  toggle,
  eventSession,
}) => {
  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: `eventProposalSession[${index}].proposalSessionTickets`,
  });

  const watchFieldArray = watch(
    `eventProposalSession[${index}].proposalSessionTickets`
  );
  const controlledFields = fields.map((field, index) => {
    return {
      ...field,
      ...watchFieldArray[index],
    };
  });

  const handleAddEventSession = () => {
    append({});
  };

  return (
    <label
          className="font-bold mr-3"
          htmlFor={`eventProposalSession[${index}].startSessionDate`}
        >
          Start
        </label>
        <input
          type="date"
          className="w-1/5 h-12 border-2 border-dotted border-black rounded-xl p-4 mr-7 focus:outline-none"
          name={`eventProposalSession[${index}].startSessionDate`}
          id={`eventProposalSession[${index}].startSessionDate`}
          {...register(`eventProposalSession[${index}].startSessionDate`, {
            required: "Start session date field is required",
          })}
        />
        {errors?.[eventProposalSession]?.[index]?.startSessionDate && (
          <span>
            {errors.eventProposalSession[index].startSessionDate.message}
          </span>
        )}
};
```

I useFieldArray in the eventSession. I want check error in EventProposalSession but can't find the error. How can I get the error if the eventProposalSession[${index}].startSessionDate is empty ? I try to console.log it but it seem undifined